# Query range not equal to zero

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm in AX 2012 R2 environment.

I would like to add a query range to HcmEmployment table and filter out rows that have a LegalEntity value = 0.

The following code fails at runtime with the exception "Invalid Range".

```
qbrLegalEntity = qbds.addRange(fieldNum(HcmEmployment, LegalEntity));
strRangeCondition = '(%1 != %2)';
qbrLegalEntity.value(strFmt(strRangeCondition, 
                        fieldStr(HcmEmployment, LegalEntity),
                        queryValue("0")));
```

Is it possible to code this range condition?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not make it harder:

```
qbds.addRange(fieldNum(HcmEmployment,LegalEntity)).value(SysQuery::valueNot(0));
```

The reason for your failed query expression was the use of `queryValue("0")` which quotes the zero. Changing that to `0` would work as well, but again too laborious.

And even shorter is:

```
qbds.addRange(fieldNum(HcmEmployment,LegalEntity)).value('!0');
```

To diagnose query errors take a look on the SQL generated:

```
info(qbds.toString());
```

Comment: Sorry, getting the same error - Invalid Range.

Both SysQuery::valueNot and the value methods return a string and LegalEntity is an int. So, the "Invalid Range" message makes sense. Am I missing something?

Comment: You must have messed something else up. `SysQuery::value` and `valueNot` returns a string, because that is the only thing the `value` functions accepts.

Comment: SELECT  FROM HcmEmployment(HcmEmployment) WHERE HcmWorker.RecId = HcmEmployment.Worker AND ((NOT (LegalEntity = 0)))

Comment: I'd made a mistake. My queryBuildDataSource was pointing to the wrong table. The code now runs without the "Invalid Range" exception. However, it doesn't produce the intended result. The range (not equal to 0) is not being enforced. The string represenattion of teh query is as follows: SELECT FROM HcmEmployment(HcmEmployment) WHERE HcmWorker.RecId = HcmEmployment.Worker AND ((NOT (LegalEntity = 0)))

Comment: Is this a part of a join? It is difficult to guess what the problem is without the proper context. If you publish the form or whatever, chances would be better. Besides, the question as stated is answered, so it would be better to post a new question.

Comment: Yes, it is part of a join and I think that is the reason I'm getting these records. It appears that the predicate is evaluated on the table before the join and not after the join.