# How to Remove zero amount line fom axapta form by code

Tags: forms, filter, axapta, x++

When we are processing EOS(end of service) of an employee then system automatically generate the zero line 0.00 as Encashment quantity for rendom employee somehow.My client don't want this zero line in this form becuase when they are trying to post EOS to general ledger its showing the error as amount can't be post without value.So how to code in x++ to remove the zero amount line from my EOS form if there is any 0.00 encashment amount.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dq9sz.png)

In Above screenshot system has calculated the encashment quantity as zero so when we processed EOS. Kindly requesting give some suggestions to handle this scenario by X++ code.

Comment: Do you have any code to start with?

Comment: No actually I am new in axapta.I am confused where to do that code.

Comment: How is the processing of the end of service of an employee triggered in the application? Could you include a menu path and a short process description in your question? Or is it a customization? Also what version of Dynamics is being used?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a datasource to get the value then there is a property called "Insert if empty" on the datasource (In this case the datasource with the EncashmentQuantity field) which is automatically set as "yes" but you can change it to "no" and the value should not be shown if it is 0. I am not sure this is what you are talking about but it might be.

Answer (score 0):

I hope to understood the question.

*"My client don't want this zero line in this form becuase...."*

I think you have this way, If you want to filter the record without 0 Value by code, you can use filter in *DataSource* rightClick override *executequery* method and insert code looklike follow:

```
public void executeQuery()
{    
    this.query().dataSourceTable(tableNum(**YourTablename**)).addRange(fieldNum(**YourTableName**,**YoutFilterField**)).value(strFmt("%1", '>0'));
    super();
}
```

ForExample :

```
this.query().dataSourceTable(tableNum(LedgerJournalTrans)).addRange(fieldNum(LedgerJournalTrans,AmountCurCredit)).value(strFmt("%1", '>0')); // DISCARD all record lower than 0
```

or

```
this.query().dataSourceTable(tableNum(LedgerJournalTrans)).addRange(fieldNum(LedgerJournalTrans,AmountCurCredit)).value(SysQuery::valueNot(0));
```

I share this useful links :

[Expressions in query ranges](http://mukesh-ax.blogspot.it/2011/04/query-ranges-in-x.html)

[SimilarQuestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23640946/query-range-not-equal-to-zero)

[StandardGuide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa638454.aspx)

Good work!